# How to convert a numerical date to worded date in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to use the first six digits of a field and convert it to a worded date in Excel i.e. want to convert 8305305003082 to 30 May 1980.

Thanks

Jacques

Comment: Did you mean that 8305305003082 should be 30 May 1983?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first digits use `LEFT`. For example:

- Cell `A1` value is `41680123456789`.
- Cell `B1` formula would be `UPPER(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(LEFT(A1;5));MONTH(LEFT(A1;5));DAY(LEFT(A1;5)));"dd mmmm yyyy"))`.

The result will be `10 FEBRUARY 2014`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, it helps with getting the name spelled out.  Unfortunately I don't understand how to get my example 8305305003082 to display as 30 May 1983.  Can't seem to figure out the logic, which is used to convert your first 5 numbers to 10 February 2014.  Don't see the logic in 41680.  Thanks for you reply.

Comment: The logic is: Excel treats all dates as serial numbers. It then uses formatting to present the serial number as a date. Being `1 = 1 January 1900`. That's why you won't get `30 May 1983` from `8305305003082`. The correct value is `30466`.

Comment: Is there a way to convert my 830530 to the correct serial number?

Comment: I think is too hard. Not everyone has the necessary intelligence to do it. But if you wanna try... Ok, here it is: make a simple subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that 8305305003082 should be 30 May 1983? So your number starts with yyMMdd. If your number is in cell A1 use this formula:

`=DATE(LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2),MID(A1,5,2))`

Be sure to format the cell as a date otherwise it will look just like a number e.g. 30466.